# How to exclude dll of nuget package in parent project

Tags: c#, .net, package, nuget

- Project (A)

  - have reference to some Nuget package
- Project (B)

  - have reference to project (A)
- Projects (C, D, E)

  - has references to project (B)

All projects have different output path and target framework .Net Framework 4.8.
When I build solution, dll of Nuget (which size is ~150Mb) builds in every path of parent projects.
How can I say VisualStudio to build Nuget dll's only to project (A) output path and use it from there to all parent projects?

Comment: If Project A requires a nuget package, and Project B requires Project A, then the output of Project B needs all the dlls or Project A (including its dependencies) to be available, otherwise the dependencies for Project A won't be found and you'll get a runtime crash.

Comment: All works fine if I delete these dll's from all directories except of root.
I guess that runtime load dll's to domain only from root, so I don't need dll's in rest directories